# Why does ab = nc +1 mean the same as ab $\equiv$ 1 (mod n)?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

Why does ab = nc +1 mean the same as ab $\equiv$ 1 (mod n)? Is it enough to say that since ab = nc + 1 then ab mod n = 1? Or do we need further steps to clarify?

Comment: This is literally the definition of $ab\equiv1\pmod{n}$ in most cases. There is no need for further steps (I'm assuming all variables are integers).

Comment: Use \equiv in mathjax.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ab\equiv 1\pmod n$ means that $ab-1$ is a multiple of $n$, that is, for some integer $c$, we have $ab-1=nc$. Putting $1$ to the other side gives $ab=nc+1$.

Answer (score 1):

because $n\equiv0\pmod n$ so $nc\equiv0\pmod n$ so $nc+1\equiv1\pmod n$